# EF code first - map child class property to base class table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I wonder if it's possible to map a child class property to base class table. Say I have two classes (shortened):

```cs
public abstract class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    // other properties...
}
```

and

```cs
public class Customer : User
{
    public int ShopId { get; set; }

    public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }

    // other properties...
}
```

I'm using TPT (table per type) inheritance (that means two tables - User and Customer). For some reasons I would like to have the `ShopId` property in the User table, but all other properties from `Customer` class in the Customer table. Is that even possible?

Having ShopId column in User table would allow us for example to create unique index on Username and ShopId (the application is multi-tenant so we don't want globally unique usernames, only shop-level unique usernames).

Comment: so why cant you put shopId in user?  ef isnt going to create a table for abstracts either.

Comment: It is when using TPT. Moreover, I don't want to have any relation from `User` to `Shop`. `User` has nothing to do with `Shop`, only `Customer` has.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

UserBase.cs

```
public abstract class UserBase
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }
}
```

User.cs

```
public class User : UserBase
{
    // user specific properties...
}
```

Customer.cs

```
public class Customer : UserBase
{
    // customer specific properties...
}
```

UserDbContext.cs

```
public class UserDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...

    protected override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // if you want users and customers to be shop specific
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserBase>.HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.ShopId });

        // if you only want users to be shop specific uncomment below and remove above
        //modelBuilder.Entity<User>.HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.ShopId });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. I'm looking for a solution with no relation from User (base class) to Shop (at the application level). I mean, since since relation to Shop is valid only for Customer I prefer having `ShopId` and `Shop` properties only in Customer class. However, to ensure database integrity it would be ideal to have ShopId column in User table. The column mapped to property would be visible only in Customer class.

Comment: Just add a `ShopId` property to the `User` class then with no navigation property to `Shop`.